# How to drag an HTML element in TWebBrowser using IHTMLDocument2

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I use Delphi 6 with the `TWebBrowser` component and `IHTMLDocument2` interface. I put an image and I would like to drag this image over the form. In my research on the Internet, I found that I have to set the element to have an absolute position. I make this with the following code:

```pascal
HTMLDocumento := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
HTMLDocumento.queryCommandSupported('2D-Position');
HTMLDocumento.queryCommandSupported('AbsolutePosition');
```

After this, the element doesn't drag!!

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: The code shown is merely *querying* the browser whether absolute positioning is supported or not. The code is not actually *setting* anything related to that feature. So, what does THAT code look like?

Comment: what i read is,if iam not wrong, that code it works when an object/element is focused before! what you sugest!??

Comment: like I said, it is not enough to just query the features, you need to enable them. For instance: `HTMLDocumento.execCommand('2D-Position', false, true);`

Comment: i will try and keep you post!

Comment: Remy Lebeau it works! thanks a lot!!